# Any Good Website Security Tools?

Tags: php, security, jquery

I have an AJAX (jquery) based website. It has lots of ajax calls.

Anyways, I have to check whether my website is hack proof, sessions are properly maintained, etc, i mean anything that can be considered as a security flaw and patch it.

Can anyone suggest me any tools using which I can do all kinds of hack on my website to find out vulnerability?

Thanks.

EDIT:
Why will someone want to vote this question down?

Comment: Inspecting the source code should be the first thing to do.

Comment: Tools become relevant as soon as you understand how to do it manually. Then they can help you automate certain tasks that would be tedious to do by hand. Most of them assume that you don't have access to the source code, because that makes black-box checking somewhat superfluous.

Comment: I would love to do this manually if I get to know certain patterns or practices as in how other security experts do this. Any ideas?

Comment: For a start, you should read about SQL injection, XSS, file inclusion and code/shell injection vulnerabilities. More advanced topics include CSRF, session hijacking, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can recommend to you the [Burp Suite](http://portswigger.net/burp/). User friendly, many features, well documented. Also discussed in some web application security books, e.g. [The Web Application Hacker's Handbook](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470170778.html). It has both free and paid version. The free one is quite useful as well.

It is written in Java so you can use it on many platforms.

Answer (score 2):

check http://sectools.org/tag/web-scanners/

Comment: this gives me a pretty big list and being a newbie I'm confused, please can you specify any ONE good software?

Comment: @Kumar: Check w3af. Requires some knowledge to use, though.